# RxJs: finalize for not complete observable

Tags: rxjs

I have the following code:

```
this.userService.get().pipe(
  catchError(() => EMPTY) // Do something here
).subscribe(() => {}) // And here
```

I want to do some stuff no matter there was an error or not. Just like `finalize` but for not completed observable. I tried to use `tap`, but it works only if there's no error. I don't want to duplicate my code and add it to the `catchError`. What should I do?

Comment: use tap after catchError?

Answer (score 0):

there's no other way to do it with `catchError` without touching it in the current example . Because everything after `catchError` won't get any notification, it's like an observable that never emits.

you can use 2nd argument of `tap`, it is triggered on error, the same as in subscribe.

```js
this.userService.get().pipe(
  tap(
    () => console.log('emit'),
    () => console.log('error'),
    () => console.log('complete'),
  ),
  // catchError(() => EMPTY), // closing the stream and hiding the error.
  // repeat(), // in case if you want to resubscribe once the stream has been closed.
).subscribe(
    () => console.log('emit'),
    () => console.log('error'),
    () => console.log('complete'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Emit a default value in `catchError`.

```ts
this.userService.get().pipe(
  catchError(() => of(null)) // catch error and emit null instead (or some other value)
).subscribe(value => { 
  // do something here,
  // value will be null when this.userService.get() errors */ 
})
```

You should consider moving your error handling with catchError into the Service.